# Gitlab and HTML documentation

Tags: jenkins, doxygen, gitlab

My development environment consists of Git repository, GitLab repository manager and Jenkins. During build process a documentation is generated with Doxygen in HTML format.

Is it possible to store that documentation on GitLab project's wiki? I know that HTML is not supported in Gollum, which is the Gitlab's wiki engine. Converting HTML to Markdown is not satisfactory because of internal links in HTML files that point to other HTML files.

Should I store documentation in a separate wiki instead and only commit a link to GitLab project wiki?

Comment: I am interested in the answer to this question as well!

Comment: Why don't you just leave the HTML as Artefact on Jenkins?

Comment: And link from Gitlab wiki to Jenkins's artifact?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the answer depends on what you use your HTML documentation for and how much you distribute it.

First of all, which version of `Gitlab` are you using ?

1. If it is only for your developers to get access to (aka these are private documents), then on `Gitlab >= 8.1.2` there is a service called `External Wiki` that allows you to substitute the `Wiki` link of the project by any URL of your choice. Just set up a web server serving your html documentation, have your build server upload the newest version after each build and call it a day.
2. If your documentation is a code that you want to version control and distribute, then do so.

Whether you go for 1. or 2., it is still a good idea to have a the whole documentation in a separate `git` repository, because you get compression for free and using `git pull` is much better than using any `rsync` to synchronise any local or remote directories. Then is just a matter of setting up `shell` script or `git hooks` to automatically do all of it for you; either at commit or build time.

Hope this helps !