# How to create external wiki on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I am documenting a dart project. I generated HTML documentation with dartdoc. I don't want this HTML to be put in the project so I read this article: 
[Gitlab and HTML documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966292/gitlab-and-html-documentation) about external wiki.

But I can't find this option in my GitLab, so I was wondering if it is still possible or if better solutions exist to implement HTML documentation in GitLab.

Or maybe there are some ways to convert the HTML into markdown to make it easier to put on GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

External wiki settings are accessed at `https://{your_gitlab_host}/{group}/{repository}/services/external_wiki/edit`